# How to produce sound when a certain condition is met in proteus?

Tags: flipflop, speakers, counter, proteus

I've made a 6-bit counter with 6 JK flip-flops that can count from 1 to 33. After it reaches 33, the circuit will go back to zero. I want the circuit to produce a sound when the counter reaches 33. I tried using SPEAKER and AUDIO SIGNAL GENERATOR but they don't seem to work with logic gates. Is there any way to solve this without using Arduino and scripting stuff?

Here is the circuit:

[image]

Comment: FPGA? What type of sound? A square wave is simplest but has a buzzy sound.

Comment: How fast does your counter count? One step every second or a thousand steps every second? Please show us a circuit diagram (even if it doesn't work).

Comment: @Mattman944 I use the .wav extension for the beep sound

Comment: @AJN I don't know how to check  the speed of my counter. It counts only when the count button is pressed